# Install ruby 1.9.2 on debian production server

Tags: debian, ruby, debian-squeeze, rvm

I have a problem install ruby 1.9.2 on debian using rvm.

The install goes fine, and when i type

> rvm use 1.9.2

then it says:

> Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180

but when I type

> ruby -v

I get

> ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Is that in the exact same shell?

Comment: "ruby" installed at multiple locations? What does # whereis ruby return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the rvm path of ruby in front of your path in .bashrc or whatever file you use...

export PATH=$PATH_TO_RVM_RUBY:$PATH

Comment: I have tried this, but it didn't make any difference

Comment: You certainly have to load the new environment... Means => spawn a new  shell, or get an entire new login session.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the results of `rvm info` please?

Did you add the oneliner to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile then open a new shell per the post install instructions?

It would be something like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Did you do the single user install or system wide?